# How do you successfully troubleshoot a Windows Explorer hang?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Having disabled all third party extensions using Nirsoft's ShellExView, I'm left with months of

```
Description
A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: AppHangB1
Application Name:   explorer.exe
Application Version:    10.0.15063.168
Application Timestamp:  6060e2fc
Hang Signature: ce8d
Hang Type:  33554436
OS Version: 10.0.15063.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Hang Signature 1:    ce8d3f7dea89f5da745188b62ae4e305
Additional Hang Signature 2:    227c
Additional Hang Signature 3:    227c6aa3f13559e0a64598174c8404b2
Additional Hang Signature 4:    5916
Additional Hang Signature 5:    5916a56676a66702fbf95f49d596b539
Additional Hang Signature 6:    4c60
Additional Hang Signature 7:    4c604e33728afb8c5d0a90da163383be

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  81c4125bf573c243fc8d68eaa8bb1562 (129466760341)
```

What should I do next?

Running Windows 10 build 15063. The problem has existed between many builds.

Comment: Have you tried "Refreshing Windows"? https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-refresh-tool-do-clean-install-windows-10

Comment: [generate a hang dump](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kristinw/2012/10/03/procdump-how-to-properly-gather-dump-dmp-files-for-crashes-and-hangs-cpu-spikes-etc-including-gathering-perf-data-for-exchange-issues/), open it in windbg (part of SDK) and run **!analyze -v -hang** and look what windbg tells you from dump

Answer (score 1):

Instabilities in Windows Explorer are attributable to faulty shell extensions and add-ons. Disable non-Microsoft shell extensions and add-ons, and check the behavior.  If it is gone, re-enable the disabled extensions/add-ons, one at a time, and see if you can identify which may be responsible.

You can also check by safe-mode on your server:
Check the status of the issue in safe mode (safe mode with networking if this happens while browsing the Internet).
Start your computer in safe mode
Advanced startup options (including safe mode)

If the issue does not occur in safe mode or safe mode with networking then place the computer in clean boot state and check if helps you fix this issue.